# Prevent duplicate values using group by and count distinct simultaneously?

Tags: sql-server, database, group-by, count, distinct

I have a simple table with years and customer id and now I want to group by year and count distinct customers for each year. This is straightforward and works fine, my issue is that I don't want customers in year 1 to repeat in year 2, I only want to see new customers for each year. So how do I do that?

I have tried using count distinct with group by and even not in but it doesn't seem to work, it always gives me repeating values

```
select count (distinct customer ID), Year
FROM customers
group by year
```

lets say I have 100 customers for years 2015 to 2019
now I have

```
Year No of Customers
2015   30
2016   35
2017   40
2018   30
2019   10
```

Total  145 which is 45 more than 100
What I want is

```
Year  No of Customers
2015   30
2016   30
2017   20
2018   20
2019   10
Total  100
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Yes its updated now its MS Sql server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to count customers in the first year they appear, then use two levels of aggregation:

```
select min_year, count(*)
from (select customerid, min(year) as min_year
      from customers c
      group by customerid
     ) c
group by min_year
order by min_year;
```

To get the `total`, you can use `grouping sets` or `rollup` (not all databases support these.  A typical method is:

```
select min_year, count(*)
from (select customerid, min(year) as min_year
      from customers c
      group by customerid
     ) c
group by min_year with rollup;
```

Comment: I will appreciate it a lot if you can explain to me, what is min(navrchar) do? is it built in function in sql? Also why are we grouping by customerid and not year?

Finally I think am getting the total but value is null under column min_year.

I did some basic testing and I think this works great, Thanks a ton. I will need to test it in different cases and soon I will mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT count (distinct c1.customerID), c1.Year 
FROM customers c1
WHERE c1.customerID not in (
    SELECT c2.customerID
    FROM customers c2
    WHERE c2.year < c1.year
)
GROUP BY year
```